# Display InputText field when checkbox is checked

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to display a textfield when 'Yes' checkbox is checked, but due to addition of lookup field value on VF page textfield is stopped displaying when I check the checkbox. That means only one textfield is showing either lookupfield or textfield when I check the checkbox. I need to show them both.

```
<apex:page standardController="Review__c" extensions="VFTestController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"> 
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title=" Review">
<apex:pageblocksection >
           <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!chkBx}" label="Yes"> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePanel" action="{!click}"/>    
            </apex:inputcheckbox> 
           <apex:inputCheckbox label="No"/>  
</apex:pageblocksection><br></br>

If Yes..
<apex:pageblocksection >
 <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel">    
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!displayInputputText}">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Text" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!Review__c.X2Yes__c}"/>  
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblocksection>


Enter Contact Name:<br></br>
<apex:inputField value="{!Review__c.Contact__c}"/>
<br></br>
<div align="center" draggable="false" >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
</div><br></br>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extentions:

```
 public Boolean displayInputputText{get;set;}
    public Boolean chkBx{get;set;}
    public String input{get;set;}       
    public PageReference click(){    
         if(chkBx){
             displayInputputText = true;
         }
         else{
             displayInputputText = false;
         }
         return null;
    }
```

Comment: What does the inputText field `!Review__c.X2Yes__c` do when you input text to it and click on Save? Does it change the value of the lookup? Knowing if there's a relationship between the two might help explain the behavior that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have kept the rendered attribute to a **pageblocksectionitem** so only that field is enabled on Check equals true.

Move that boolean to **pageblocksection** instead to enable both fields

```
<apex:pageblocksection rendered="{!displayInputputText}">
   <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel">    
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Text" />
         <apex:inputText value="{!Review__c.X2Yes__c}"/>  
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Contact Name:" />
        <apex:inputText value="{!Review__c.Contact__c}"/>  
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
   </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Comment: Still not working, I want to display Lookup inputtext field constantly and other inupttext field when I check the 'yes' checkbbox.

Comment: If I remove the "Enter Contact Name:<br></br>
<apex:inputField value="{!Review__c.Contact__c}"/> " then inputtext field is displaying. I want them both.

Comment: So if you want only the inputtext field on change, then add the **rendered** attribute in that **pageblocksectionitem** tag instead of pageblocksection.

Comment: I have done it already but not working.

Comment: Try removing **apex:outputPanel** and add the id to pageblocksection and try to rerender the pageblocksection

Comment: Still not working.